# Bad Bengali font?

Tags: fonts, language-support, internationalization

I just installed Precise in my native language (Bengali). I'd post an image, but apparently new users can't post images on this forum.

The Bengali font is oddly small and difficult to read.

I don't want to increase font size from the accessibility settings since that makes the English fonts larger too, everything takes up more space, and it just looks bad.

Is there a way to replace the Bengali font with something else, or at least increase it's size?

Comment: This question is 5+ years old and has no answers. The Ubuntu version OP was using is now EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.